# What is the colour of Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, tradition, color

I'm curious seeing everyone, who identifies as "*kattar Hindu*", sport a **saffron** cloth on their shoulders as they shove their way into hostile muslim areas.

I understand there can't be just one colour that symbolises Hinduism in general however,

1. What are the colours that are considered auspicious or inauspicious in Hinduism?
2. What is the shāstrik justification for the same?
3. Out of all the auspicious colours, is there any that's considered supreme of all? If so, why?

Comment: Colours which are generally bright are considered auspicious. Black is generally considered inauspicious. However, there isn't any specific colour designated by the Hindu scriptures to be the symbol of dharma.

Comment: Regarding the association of saffron with Hindu militancy, it goes back to the use of the bhagwa dhvaja by Chhatrapati Shivaji. The Maratha Empire is popularly described as a kingdom created in the name of upholding Hinduism agaisnt Islamic rule, which is an exaggeration & propaganda. Although the term 'bhagwa' is translated to saffron, the actual colour is actually ochre, a pigment obtained from a special variety of soil. Hence use of an ochre flag was to portray their status as 'sons of the soil'.

Comment: @অনু thanks for the information. If you could possibly further elaborate your comments and add aware scriptural sources to strengthen the same down at the Answers, I'm sure it'd qualify as relevant.

Comment: Usage of colors, depends on the context.

Comment: @Bingming can you please shed more light on your comment and elaborate it down in the Answers?

Comment: @SouravBhatnagar Unfortunately, I don't have anything answer-worthy to the question of this post, at the moment. If I do have, I will share. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Any bright color, as অনু has pointed out... Excluding darker colors is good. The reason for excluding black is that Rahu and Saturn are associated with that, both of those Grahas are related to filth and suffering, mental and physical, respectively. And, muted colors naturally propose a bit of a reduction on the 'confidence' of a color.

Yellow is the most auspicious color when it comes to Dharma related things. Many hindu kingdoms of the past also had this color (typically along with the Sun and the Moon in the flag).

[image]
Also, keep in mind that before modern times, basically the only source for yellow dye was turmeric.

The reason for this is that Devaguru Brihaspati (the guru of long term, beneficial qualities within humans*) is associated with a bright form of yellow (with a slight amount of red mixed in), that's similar to turmeric. Moreover, the 9th Bhaava (section), called **Dharma** has the exact same color in Jyotisham, so it is literally the color of Dharma. Adhyaaya 55 in the second Pada of the Narada Purana has these details. Brihaspatyacharya also has a very high position, possibly the highest, in relation of matters in Dharma. Shukracharya does too, but since he's the guru of Asuras, he comes second, as far as humans are concerned.

Of course, white (wealth, purity, peace), with a slight tinge of yellow like the color of the moon at moon-noon is pretty great as well as red (advancement and power), the color of the sun at sunrise in terms of worldly matters. Saffron is also good as it relates to Karma. A brighter form of brown is also good as it indicates natural abundance of abilities that causes prosperity. But, as far as Dharma is concerned, bright yellow is the one.

I'm not aware of any good ancient source that mentions or hints Saffron for Dharma. It doesn't really fit. The 'feeling' of saffron is more like the feeling of 12pm, whereas the feeling of Dharma is more like 2 pm.

Saffron for Dharma is more like a political/militant symbol of some sort of resistance/power, rather than of Dharma itself, in current use, anyways. Even in terms of the actual state of reality, if you can feel the color, then saffron is more like exercise, whereas Dharma (Yellow) is like drinking a late morning tea in a garden, it doesn't quite fit. Saffron is definitely more fit to be left to Karma, as the scriptures already suggest with regards to Jyotisham.

*I'm not saying that Devas don't actually exist.

Comment: Also, scientific dark colors absorb heat.

Comment: Dark colours, especially Black is considered inauspicious as suggested but, here in southern part of India I could notice the Ayyappa Swamy devotees adorning total black clothing without footwear. Is it got more to do with their belief system being avedik? Lastly, Isn't black associated with Yama and Shani Deva too?

Comment: @SouravBhatnagar Saturn = Shanaishchara, although it's wrong to think of him as entirely negative, the natural qualities at-least, produce दुःख, so it's considered bad in general. As for the black clothing, from the little I've researched, it appears that they wear it as a symbol for showing their detachment from bad thoughts/circumstances (which will for sure occur by them wearing black). Wearing black isn't forbidden or 'avedic', it's just that you should understand what will happen to you due to the symbols of the Graha (Saaturn+Rahu) that you're wearing so most people choose not to do so.

Comment: Also, in regards to Yama, he designates the amount of suffering/prosperity you will receive, based on your Karma, a lot like Shani. Which makes sense, since Shanaischara is his brother. In that sense, black/blue is associated with him. It is certainly a bad indication. That doesn't really affect the position/divinity of Devas though. Rahu is arguably the Graha which provides most suffering, yet he is still worshiped as a form of Naraayana,